# php losing form fields on big file upload

Tags: php, forms, apache

so i've read that php clears the $_POST variable when an upload or other data exceeds the limits on POST data. Thus if the user uploads a really big file which php/apache rejects, their form fields will get cleared out and you wont be able to repopulate them.  is there a way to get around this?  Is this a php issue or an apache issue?

Comment: There is no such thing as `$_FORM` in PHP, there's `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: ... and `$_FILES`. Which one do you mean?

Comment: sorry, guys!  i meant _POST not _FORM.  I'll edit to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to get around this?

Many ways, one of them is just to give a 500 response and dying straight away.

> Is this a php issue or an apache issue?

Can be both, but I assume it's just that you're hitting the PHP limit for post max size or the memory limit. [Configure your server that you have enough resources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) to handle the file uploads you wish.

Comment: well what i would like to do is if they send something that is too big, to spit back a message that they uploaded too big of a file, but still have their form fields filled out from the last post.  Is this possible?

Comment: Only if you put the previous form user data into a session so you can fall back in case of destroyed post submission data.